# Camel + MongoDB tailable cursor issue

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

Has anyone noticed an anomaly when using camel-mongodb component with persistentTailTracking? In particular, cursor persistence to the database doesn't happen. It creates a document with persistentId but not the lastValue.
Code is quite simple and the issue is 100% reproducible for me. Also tested with another regular capped collection.

```
from("mongodb:mongoBean?database=local&collection=oplog.rs&tailTrackIncreasingField=ts&persistentId=oplogProcessor&persistentTailTracking=true&tailTrackDb=trackers&tailTrackCollection=camelTrackers&tailTrackField=lastValue")
.to("direct:test");
```

I think it may somehow relate to issue CAMEL-9826 as the cursor thread doesn't stop on shutdown and keeps running with full CPU utilisation until I kill java process.
MongoDB log shows

```
2016-04-12T09:37:21.468+1000 I -        [conn5] Assertion: 16089:Cannot kill pinned cursor: 19377690051
```

Exactly the same Camel code using the same MongoDB Java Driver version works fine with MongoDB 2.6 but not 3.2.

Environment: OSX 10.11.4, Camel 2.16.1, Mongo Java Driver 3.2.2, MongoDB 2.6.11 / 3.2.4 / 3.2.0

Camel context is defined from Spring and the project runs as web application with mvn run:jetty.

*Edit*: Also found this issue on MongoDB Jira but not sure of the relevance
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21710